# How does the CSGO penalty system work?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So just now i was playing a csgo competitive game, there was an obvious troll on the team, duo q'ing with his friend. He would randomly kill him self (kill in console), or sit in a corner of the map looking at it jumping up and down for the whole round.

It gets even worse, I would be somewhere trying to hold a spot, he would just randomly shoot me, he shot me from 100 hp to 38, shooting me 1 bullet every few seconds.

He did not get a penalty for that.

I was so frustrated that I decided to do the same thing, except for I did at the beginning of the game and I was kicked and banned for 2 hours.

So my question is how does it give out a penalty? Why doesn't it give a penalty for him shooting me? For the banned timer, I got banned once before and it was 30 min, does this timer ever reduce?

Comment: There is a damage limit that you can give to your friends. I dont think anyone knows how much is this. But you are right, when you damage your teammate at begining of a round it bans instantly because it is clear that it is intended. probably 30-40 hp damage is enough to get banned.

Comment: But he kept shooting me, slowly but he kept shooting, and i went down to 38 hp or something like that, he did that a few rounds in a row but did not get banned, i was super surprised when i got banned . Is there a reason for that?

Comment: You can report people through the scoreboard, yeah?

Comment: I didnt see  the reporting system work for once. It is just a placebo. as I said earlier at the start even afew dmg can get you banned. in normal game time, you need to kill 3 person or damage 200-300 hp

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ban systems works as follows:

```
1st infraction: 30 min.
2nd infraction: 2 hours.
3rd infraction: 24 hours
4th infraction: 7 days
```

Any one of these infractions get reset after 7 days.

How the banning system works (To the extent of my knowledge):

```
1. Dealing 80/90+ damage to a teammate at start of game will be instant ban.
2. Doing 400+ of damage to teammate(s) over the period of the whole game can get you banned. (You usually get a warning telling you that you have done a lot of damage and the next time you attack a friendly you will be kicked)
3. Killing 3 teammates
```

How you got kicked and he didn't:
He didn't get kicked purely because it wasn't at the start of the game and in spawn. When it's like that the game knows that there are enemies around and sometimes that you are likely to either accidentally attack your team mate or maybe even kill him. For this they make exceptions. However if you were to do it as a continuous burst of fire (so all his bullets hit you without any pause) then he would have gotten kicked/banned.

In cases like that all can really do is report him through the use of the scoreboard as someone has mentioned in the comments section.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Your ban level is only decreased by one level every seven days. Therefore if you are banned for 7 days (lets call it level 4), you would have to go for 28 days without committing an offence for the ban level to completely reset (next offence would result in a 30 minute ban (level 1)).

Comment: Slight mistake in the above comment by myself. The cooldown only starts after the ban has expired, so it would actually take you 35 days to completely reset. The ban level can actually go above level 4 as well, but the ban duration never exceeds 7 days.

Answer (score 10):

### Competitive matchmaking cooldown offences:

- **Abandoning**: leaving the match at any point before the end (warm-up included)
- **Idling / AFKing**: after a set period of time (not sure how long) with no activity you will be removed
- **Excessive team-kicking**: unsure of how many kicks constitutes excessive, but this does not result in a removal, only a cooldown
- **Excessive team-killing**: after team killing for the third time in one match you will be removed
- **Excessive team-damaging**: after dealing a set amount of damage in one match you will be removed (believed to be around 500 and includes over-kill damage)
- **Excessive team-damaging at the start of a round**: the damage thresh-hold is reduced at the start of the round. You can therefore be kicked for doing less than normal damage thresh-hold in the first moments of the round (unfortunately I don't know how long this lasts for or what it is reduced to)

Regarding excessive team-damage and over-kill. You will often see a player team kill with an AWP to the head. This results in about 400 damage and means the next team damage caused by that player normally results in a kick.

### Cooldown offence levels and lengths:

- **Level 1**: 30 minutes
- **Level 2**: 2 hours
- **Level 3**: 24 hours
- **Level 4**: 7 days

#### Cooldown resets:

- Every cooldown received increases your current offence level by 1 (your offence level starts from 0)
- Offence levels can be decreased by 1 by going 7 days without receiving a cooldown
- The 7 days does not begin until your current cooldown has expired
- Offence levels can rise above level 4, but 7 days is the maximum cooldown duration
- Confusion can arise for extreme abusers when the offence level goes over 4

#### An example:

A player reaches offence level 4 and gets their first 7 day cooldown on January 1st. The cooldown expires on January 8th. The player can now play in competitive matchmaking again, but their offence level is still 4.

They receive another cooldown on January 9th and receive another 7 day cooldown (because they were still offence level 4), their offence level rises to 5. Their ban expires on January 16th and they don't commit any offences for a week. Their offence level drops back to 4.

Essentially, if you get your second or third 7 day cooldown in a row, it means you need to have two or three clean weeks after it expires before your offence level drops below 4 and therefore will receive cooldown lengths other than 7 days.

Source:
[Cooldown reset information](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/864959336634313487/)