# Does the game punish for killing a defusing teammate?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In low-level play every now and then a teammate kills a defusing friendly player to boost his own score (defusing the bomb grants 4 points) in the competitive mode. Outside of [standard penalties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150293/198327) for team-killing, is there any punishment specifically for this practice? If there isn't, killing off team players is beneficial for the backstabber and even "advised" on the last round before halftime.

Comment: I think it's just the standard team killing penalties that apply. In theory if you do this every game you might get reported more, but I don't think anything specific exists for killing somebody to steal the defuse.

Answer (score 5):

Though there is no specific penalty for killing a teammate that is defusing in CS:GO there is a system in place that will kick/ban you for dealing too much damage to teammates. When killing a number of teammates a player will be banned from the game. This ban can be temporary or permanent depending on how many times this person has misbehaved.

In short, no there is not a defuse killing specific penalty in the game.

If you want to have some in depth knowledge about the very specifics of weapons dealing damage I suggest checkin [this page](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Friendly_fire)