# Specific Rules for Start of Round Damage

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm interested in how the CS:GO start of round damage penalty works. I've looked around online and there's no consistent answer. I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/how-does-the-csgo-penalty-system-work) which answers general questions about the system, but I'm looking for details specific to start of round damage limits, ban parameters. Furthermore, it suggests that you cannot kill teammates at round start which I know to be false (I enjoy a little bit of trolling my discord friends).

Sometimes I get banned, sometimes I don't, but I've never really paid attention to the variables at play.
Distance from spawn? Time after round start? Number of shots required? Overkill amount?

Comment: you've said that you cannot kill teammates at round start, but all available resources suggest that this isn't true, or is a bug. Do you have any more information about how you can kill people at round start without being kicked?

Comment: Just yesterday I bought nova and held down m1 on my friends head and went on to lose the round.
I have a growing suspicion that this only happens with one-shots on first frame after round start. I suspect there is a tiny frame where you have agency but spawnprotectiontime hasn't started.

Comment: very interesting. I hope I have time to test your theory soon

Comment: Going into a competitive match to test the hypothesis. Potential 2hr incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal 80 damage or more within `mp_spawnprotectiontime` seconds of round start (default is 5), you will be kicked and temporarily banned.
** Credit to Nick S

However, when using a weapon that does more than 80 damage to teammates, you can avoid this by shooting on the first frame of agency. This can be achieved by aiming and holding down the fire button. I am not sure why this happens but I assume it is a bug as follows:

The sequence of operations at round start gives agency to the player before it starts a timer for `mp_spawnprotectiontime` that counts total damage during that time. Because the player gets agency before this timer starts, you can kill a teammate without being kicked and tempbanned.

This is just a theory which you could try to verify. However, my curiosity has been satisfied. Regardless, if anyone goes datamining, I'd be happy to see it!

Comment: This information is now out of date. I don't care to read the changelogs and see when it happened, but the system is clearly different now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [win.gg](https://win.gg/news/should-csgo-have-a-forgive-option-for-killing-teammates-question-mark/):

> Deal 80 or more team damage at the start of a round

> Accumulate 400 team damage across rounds

> Kill three teammates

Additionally, it seems like there is a default value for `mp_spawnprotectiontime` of 5 seconds, which means that if someone kills within 5 seconds of spawn, they will be kicked.

Comment: Useful information, but it doesn't explain how one can get kills off spawn.